# EC2 instance from custom image not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have made an ec2 instance which has all the setup for **scraping** scripts. I have made a batch file inside the startup folder which initiates the **scraping**. I have made an image out of the instance so that i can create new instance from image to run **scraping** and close the instance once done. I have an api to create instance

```
class Scraping(APIView):
    #authentication_classes = ()
    #permission_classes = ()
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = request.data
            
            source_id =data.get("source_id", None)
            ami_id =data.get("ami_id", None)

            if source_id:
                response = ec2_client.run_instances(
                    ImageId= ami_id if ami_id else 'ami-055d3dd55541f9072', #Windows v8
                    # ImageId='ami-0ecde67950acf6a97', #linux
                    InstanceType='t2.micro',
                    KeyName="Medeina-key-pair",
                    MaxCount=1,
                    MinCount=1,
                    UserData=json.dumps({"source_id":source_id}),
                    # VpcId= ["vpc-08d59eefd0b3b065b"],
                    SubnetId= "subnet-003e0da9f9865613b",
                    SecurityGroupIds=[
                        'sg-09032c4a0c4au9b51', # WINDOWS
                    ],
                    TagSpecifications=[
                        {
                            'ResourceType': "instance",
                            'Tags': [
                                {
                                    'Key': 'Name',
                                    'Value': 'Medeina_scraping_copy_' + str(source_id)
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                    ],
                )
                print(response)
                return Response({'message': "Instance created"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) 

            return Response({'message': "Please provide source"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 
        except Exception as exe:
            return Response({'message': str(exe)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

After hitting this api, the instance is created but the issue is, the batch file is not running.
The moment i access the created instance, the batch file runs automatically just like i wanted without any issue. Is this the problem related to instance authentication?
There is no error in batch file. i guess the issue is how i create the instance. Have anyone faced this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "a batch file inside the startup folder"? What is a 'startup folder'?

Comment: The instance is windows instance. So i have a batch file which run some script. I placed it in startup folder. Whatever script/batch/software you place inside the startup folder , will run automatically on windows bootup

Comment: Sounds like it only runs things on user login, not computer startup. You should be asking this at https://serverfault.com/ since StackOverflow is for Programming Q&A, but this issue is related to the Operating System.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for guiding